# return value of new in java

Tags: java

What would be the return value of new in java in case of insufficient memory? I have the following code

```
TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(n);
if(newNode == null)
    return false;
```

eclipse says that it is a dead code. How should we check for memory error in java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OutOfMemoryError` will be thrown.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because
>   it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the
>   garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

It will throw exception from that line, not return, and eclipse says dead because eclipse says that it is a dead code because you are checking `newNode` that is just initialized

Answer (score 0):

Java raises an `OutOfMemoryError` in case there is not enough memory to allocate your object: [docu link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)

To check for this, you would have to enclose your code in a `try-catch` clause:

```
TreeNode newNode;
try {
   newNode = new TreeNode(n);
}
catch( OutOfMemoryError e ) {
   // do some error handling
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
TreeNode newNode = null;
try {
    newNode = new TreeNode(n);
}
catch(final java.lang.OutOfMemoryError e ) {
    /* handle out of memory */ 
}
```